# Why Lavarand (as opposed to other methods of generating random seeds)?

Tags: randomness, random-number-generator

Cloudflare famously uses a wall of lava lamps (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavarand) to seed random number generators. But if you're going into the real world to seed your rng, why lava lamps? Why not roll 1000 D20's (say dice with 20 different colored faces) and call it a day? Is it just to look cool, or does the distribution of states that lava lamps take have a unique (or rare) property?

Comment: Commenting as I don't know this with enough certainty for an answer, but I would wager dollars to donuts that the reason Cloudflare uses the lava lamps is because it's a kind of homage to SGI's original lava lamp RNG.

Answer (score 1):

Cynical answer: Because lava lamps are pretty and the wall of lava lamps makes good marketing and it sounds impressive and conveys the impression that they are serious about security.

In practice, if all you care about is engineering, it suffices to seed a [cryptographic strength pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) with a random seed.  Most computers already contain perfectly reasonable ways to seed them, and most processors have built-in hardware support for generating random numbers that can be used to seed them.  For instance, Intel has [RDRAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND), which reads from a hardware random number generator built into the processor.  If you are using a processor that does not have this kind of support and you are paranoid, you can buy a [hardware random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) device.

Rolling dice requires human assistance, so is less preferable than the other alternatives.

You can read a lot more on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

I think you'll find https://security.stackexchange.com/q/204870/971 and https://security.stackexchange.com/q/191296/971 highly relevant. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/q/42428/971, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomness, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entropy, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entropy.